# Help explain the notation $P_{\alpha - 3}(8y)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem**
Let $$P_n(x) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{8}x + \cdots + (-1)^n \dfrac{1.3.5 \cdots (2n - 3)}{2.4.6 \cdots 2n}x^n$$
Prove that if $\alpha = 8y + 1$ and $\alpha \geq 3$, then $P_{\alpha - 3}(8y)^2$ is a solution to $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^\alpha}$.

I'm really confused about that notation. Is 
$$P_{\alpha - 3}(8y)^2 = P_{\alpha - 3}(64y^2) \text{ or } P^2_{\alpha - 3}(8y) ?$$

Thanks

Comment: You could always plug in some numbers and see which of the alternatives that seems to satisfy the statement that you're supposed to prove. (I'm too lazy to do that myself now.) :)

Comment: This is certainly a good case for parentheses.  As it is so easy to take the square inside in the first case, I'm with Gerry.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were to use that notation, I'd mean the second of your alternatives, not the first.